# Why is Laravel paginate() not working as expected but simplePaginate() does?

Tags: php, laravel-5.8, laravel-pagination

I have a model named `Conversation`. I want to show all the rows in the view by paginating them. I know to use the `paginate()` method or `simplePaginate()` method to paginate the results.

In my case both `paginate()` and `simplePaginate()` paginates the results as expected. I want to display the pagination links in my blade file. I also know that the `links()` method is used to do so.

But the problem is that when I use `paginate()`, the `links()` method doesn't work at all. And it works when I use `simplePaginate()`. I don't want to use `simplePaginate()` because it shows only **previous** and **next** links.

Here's a minimal code that I'm using:

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/conversations', 'RouteController@conversations')->name('conversations');
```

**RouteController.php**

```
class RouteController extends Controller {

    public function conversations(Request $request) {
        $conversations = Conversation::paginate(10);
        return view('conversations')->with('conversations', $conversations);

        // I also tried return view('conversations', compact('conversations));
    }
}
```

**conversations.blade.php**

```
..
<div>
    {{ $conversations->links() }}
</div>
..
```

I read the documentation and everything seems fine in the code. The interesting part is that it was working a day before when I left off!

I don't understand why is this happening?
Is this the expected behavior? or something that I'm missing?

Comment: Did you tried `{!! $conversations->render() !!}` in blade instead of `links()` ? Also check if it required css class to display it properly, inspect element and check if its there or not ? Also try publishing default paginate resources `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`

Comment: Yes, I tried `{!! $conversations->render() !!}` too. And on inspecting the element is not there in the html. Your third solution worked i.e. `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination`. If you could post this as an answer then I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel paginate vendor resource

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Further more, wherever you use any package which needs resources like config

```
datatables
datatables-buttons
datatables-fractal
datatables-html
laravel-errors
laravel-mail
laravel-notifications
laravel-pagination
```

Just type this `php artisan vendor:publish` to get all default vendor you need to publish.